# How to prevent Wix from removing registry entries on uninstall?

Tags: windows, wix, wix3.5

```
 <RegistryKey Id="MyServerRegInstallDir" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\MyApp\Server" Action="create">
     <RegistryValue Name="InstallDir" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />
     <RegistryValue Name="DataDirectory" Type="string" Value="[MYAPPDATADIR]" />
  </RegistryKey>
```

The subkeys InstallDir and DataDirectory is deleted on uninstall. How do I prevent it?

Ideally Action="create" must do it.

Comment: What is the purpose of leaving data in the registry after the program is removed?

Comment: When the application is installed again it can recover.

Comment: I've given you a pointer to something that might work below.  But I agree with kiamlaluno, your uninstaller should do its best to putting the machine in a clean state when it uninstalls.  Because if your settings are corrupt and causes the app to get into a bad state, the classic "uninstall then reinstall" solution won't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the Permanent="yes" attribute on the parent component.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_component.htm

> `Permanent`     `YesNoType`
>
> If this attribute is set to 'yes', the installer does not remove the
> component during an uninstall. The installer registers an extra system
> client for the component in the Windows Installer registry settings
> (which basically just means that at least one product is always
> referencing this component). Note that this option differs from the
> behavior of not setting a guid because although the component is
> permanent, it is still patchable (because Windows Installer still
> tracks it), it's just not uninstallable.

Comment: the link is outdated, now it's http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html

Comment: I had to add a Guid to my component to have permanent="yes" be effective